Does item damage stack with Scrolls of Power in Dead Cells?
In Dead Cells, there are weapon stat boosters called Scrolls of Power.

As you can see in the image, they might say something like “+15% damage with RED items”.
Will that +15% always be a percentage of the original (un-boosted) item, or will it stack with itself and add +15% to its current damage?

When the player picks a scroll stat, the damage of items scaling with this stat is increased by +15%. The scaling formula is identical for all colors:

if one picks a Brutality stat, the DPS of Brutality-scaling items will increase by 15%
if one picks a Tactics stat, the DPS of Tactics-scaling items will increase by 15%
if one picks a Survival stat, the DPS of Survival-scaling items will increase by 15%

This is a cumulative multiplier applied to an item's base DPS as the player's stat number increases.
The formula used is the same for all colors:

[Base DPS] × 1.15(Stats - 1)

Source, Dead Cell wiki.
